# Do I need to put "the" before "contemporary" in this context?

Tags: articles

> Here I am going to talk about this problem in **the** contemporary
>   Tajikistan.

Is "the" required in the above sentence? I could find many instances of both contemporary with and without "the" on the web. I tried "the contemporary" with the name of different country after it, and I found many examples. I also tried the same without "the", again many examples. But the latter seems to be more frequent. Also, I have seen many "in the contemporary world", but then "the world" is correct itself, while "the Tajikistan" is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, *the* is not required, and indeed would not be said by a native speaker.

Apart from a few places whose name includes "the", such as "The United Kingdom", we don't use "the" with proper names *unless* there is a certain kind of qualifying phrase following the name (I don't give the details here, as they are quite complicated, and not relevant to the question).

Comment: For the exception, presumably you mean cases where the nouns are joined with qualifying phrases in order to strongly emphasize the differences between versions (e.g. "The France of the 13th Century was quite different from the France of today" or a protest like "This is not the Britain that I know and love!"), but there's a similar exception possible even without a qualifying phrase after: "Hi, this is Hugh Grant; I'd like to make a restaurant reservation." "Oh, wow, *the* Hugh Grant?" In such cases, too, the fact that there would otherwise be different possible referents is being emphasized.

Comment: What about this example: I am familiar with such debates about *the* German language. Should *the* be there or not?

Comment: _German_, though a proper name, is functioning as an adjective. (In many languages, such national adjectives are not written treated as proper names, and not capitalised). My answer did not allow for this case. _The German language_ is no different in structure from _the red book_.